# classification report for multilabel text classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I'm working on multilabel text classification.
I'm tried to print the classification report for the machine learning but its print for each class alone.
how I can get the classification report for all classes together?
This part of the code

this code for the labels

```
categories = list(data_raw.columns.values)
categories = categories[1:]
```

The Evaluation:

```
def modelEvaluation(predictions, y_test_set):
    print("\nAccuracy on validation set: {:.4f}".format(accuracy_score(y_test_set, predictions)))
    print("\nClassification report : \n", metrics.classification_report(y_test_set, predictions))
    print("\nConfusion Matrix : \n", multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_test_set, predictions))
```

and this for ML

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC


SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
            ])


for category in categories:
    printmd('**Processing {} comments...**'.format(category))
    
    # Training logistic regression model on train data
    SVC_pipeline.fit(x_train, train[category])
    
    # calculating test accuracy
    prediction = SVC_pipeline.predict(x_test)
    print('Test accuracy is {}'.format(accuracy_score(test[category], prediction)))
    print("\n")
    
    modelEvaluation(prediction, test[category])
```

if I tried to print the classification report alone like the below code, it gives me the result for the last class

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print("\nClassification report : \n", metrics.classification_report(test[category], prediction))
```

Comment: Please select and upvote answer if it helped.

Answer (score -1):

Use **without** `test[category]` and provide the whole test set which contains all classes that you build your model for.

```
print("\nClassification report : \n", metrics.classification_report(y_test, predictions))
```

Where `y_test` is ground truth labels (True outputs) for test set `X_test`.

You are passing test set (`X_test`) instead of labels (`y_test`) for that test set.

Comment: Please check the modification of the question to see how the class label was determined. By the way, I tried your solution, but it's not working gave me an error.
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: You should comment back if the solution works or not so that we can know what's the problem.

Comment: For the `TypeError` you gave. Please add the full tracevack error to know which line is problem. And again to get classification report for all classes you need test set with all those classes not just a single class/category.

Comment: `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-056fdfcdc434> in <module>
      2 test = test.drop(labels = ['story'], axis=1)
      3 
----> 4 print("\nClassification report : \n", metrics.classification_report(test, prediction))
      5 print(test)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)`
@Anurag Dhadse

Comment: `y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
   1930 
   1931     labels_given = True

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     89     if len(y_type) > 1:
     90         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
---> 91                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
     92 
     93    # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets`

Comment: `ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets
`
This is the last error

Comment: What is the shape of `test` and `predictions` ? Both should have single digit values not hot-encoded vector. Tell the shape of both of them.

Comment: the shape of predictions is (18759,)
test.shape 
(18759, 8)

Comment: Got it. Classification report expects its inputs to be `y_true, predictions` and NOT `X_test, predictions`( your `test` is `X_test`; input to test on).  You are passing test set instead of labels for that test set. Updated ans